# How to wrap content of H1 tag

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, css, tags

I am unable to explain my question. But if anyone understood what I want please do edit.

I have following code

```
<table style="width:100%">

        <tr style="border-style: none solid solid solid; border-width: thin; border-color: #C0C0C0; background-color: #FFFFFF">
            <td class="style4" width="100%" 

                style="border-bottom-style: solid; border-bottom-width: thin; border-bottom-color: #C0C0C0" 
                align="left">
                <h1 style="font-style: normal; font-weight: normal;">
                            <%=t.getTitle() %>
                </h1>
```

Whenever `t.getTitle()` returns a larger string that is in one line, my heading goes out of the page (overflow). I want to wrap the content of `h1` into `td` having it.

Like stackoverflow.com uses for its question titles.

Comment: While you probably don't want to do this, you might hide the overflow using CSS: style="overflow:hidden;"

Comment: The code in the question is incomplete (it does not even close the table) and does not reproduce the problem. Please post a minimal code that actually demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quite seldom, text overflows text-boxes. In such cases, one can force the browser to change wrapping. [web designer wall](http://webdesignerwall.com/) explains it [here](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/word-wrap-force-text-to-wrap):

```
.break-word {
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Changes rendering behavior like this:

[image]

Additionally, while maybe not helpful in the current situation, one may **hide any overflow** using CSS:

```
style="overflow:hidden;"
```

*PS: Actually, I wonder, if word-wrap is the root cause your problem.*

Comment: Breaking words is not correct for English and many other languages. So the proposed solution would solve a very limited set of problems, and the real problem has not been disclosed yet.

Comment: Actually, the image is linked to web designer wall's site, owned by Nick La - living in Canada ;-) Did you fix the wording of my post?

Answer (score 0):

1000 words will be wrapped.
1 word with 1000 character won't be wrapped.
Try:

```
word-wrap:break-word;
```